# How to clean up or smoothen a time series using two criteria in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

Sorry for the confusing title. I'm trying to clean up a dataset that has engine hours reported on different time intervals. I'm trying to detect and address two situations:

1. Engine hours reported are less than last records engine hours
2. Engine hours reported between two dates is greater than the hour difference between said dates

   ```
   Sampled Date    Meter   eng_hours_diff  date_hours_diff
    2017-02-02     5336         24                24
    2017-02-20     5578         242               432
    2017-02-22     5625         47                48
    2017-03-07     5930         305               312
    2017-05-16     6968         1038              1680
    2017-06-01     7182         214               384
    2017-06-22     7527         345               504
    2017-07-10     7919         392               432
    2017-07-25     16391        8472              360
    2017-08-20     8590        -7801              624
    2017-09-05     8827         237               384
    2017-09-26     9106         279               504
    2017-10-16     9406         300               480
    2017-10-28     9660         254               288
    2017-11-29     10175        515               768
   ```

What I would like to do is re-write the ['Meter'] series if either of the two scenarios above come up and take the average between the points around it.

I'm thinking that this might require two steps, one to eliminate any inaccuracy due to the difference in engine hours being > than the hours between the dates, and then re-calculate the ['eng_hours_diff'] column and check if there are still any that are negative.

The last two columns I've calculated like this:

```
dfa['eng_hours_diff'] = dfa['Meter'].diff().fillna(24)

dfa['date_hours_diff'] = dfa['Sampled Date'].diff().apply(lambda x:str(x)).apply(lambda x: x.split(' ')[0]).apply(lambda x:x.replace('NaT',"1")).apply(lambda x: int(x)*24)
```

EDIT:
Ok I think I'm getting somewhere but not quite there yet..

```
dfa['MeterReading'] = [x if y>0 & y<z else 0 for x,y,z in 
                       zip(dfa['Meter'],dfa['eng_hours_diff'], dfa['date_hours_diff'])]
```

EDIT 2:

I'm much closer thanks to Bill's answer.

Applying this function will replace any record that doesn't meet the criteria with a zero. Then I'm replacing those zeros with np.nan and using the interpolate method.

The only thing that I'm missing is how to fill out the last values when they also come as np.nan, I'm looking to see if there's an extrapolate method.

Here is the function in case anyone stumbles upon a similar problem in the future:

```
dfa['MeterReading'] = dfa['MeterReading'].replace({0:np.nan}).interpolate(method='polynomial', order=2, limit=5, limit_direction='both').bfill()
```

This is the issue that I'm having at the end. Two values were missed but since the difference becomes negative it discards all 4.

[image]

Comment: If you replace missing meter readings with `np.nan` instead of zero then the `eng_hours_diff` column would also produce nans instead of negative values.  Make a separate interpolated column and then choose the final fill values based on some logic.

Comment: For the fill at the end, instead of trying to extrapolate with a polynomial (could lead to poor predictions), how about maintaining a rolling average hours/day value (or maybe simply a global average hours per day using fillna with the `ffill` method option) and then use that to extrapolate linearly past the end of the data?

Comment: That's not a bad point to do a rolling mean, in fact I could do it over the entire series because what I really care about is the approximate hours on that date, the biggest thing is that I want to remove fat-fingered entries like 1000000 hours or entries that are less than the previous one. Maybe I can simply do a ffill() and then a rolling mean over that

Comment: Sounds good.  Rolling average would be fine, or check out [exponentially-weighted moving average](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ewm.html) if the hours / day changes a lot and you want a more response filter.

Answer (score 1):

One problem with your code is that the logic condition is not doing what you want I think. `y>0 & y<z` is not the same as `(y>0) & (y<z)` (e.g. for the first row).

Putting that aside, there are in general three ways to do operations on the elements of rows in a pandas Dataframe.

For simple cases like yours where the operations are vectorizable you can do them without a for loop or list comprehension:

```
dfa['MeterReading'] = dfa['Meter']
condition = (dfa['eng_hours_diff'] > 0) & (dfa['eng_hours_diff'] < dfa['date_hours_diff'])
dfa.loc[~condition, 'MeterReading'] = 0
```

For more complex logic, you can use a for loop like this:

```
dfa['MeterReading'] = 0
for i, row in dfa.iterrows():
    if (row['eng_hours_diff'] > 0) & (row['eng_hours_diff'] < row['date_hours_diff']):
        dfa.loc[i, 'MeterReading'] = row['Meter']
```

Or, use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with a custom function like:

```
def calc_meter_reading(row):
    if (row['eng_hours_diff'] > 0) & (row['eng_hours_diff'] < row['date_hours_diff']):
        return row['Meter']
    else:
        return 0

dfa['MeterReading'] = dfa.apply(calc_meter_reading, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to put these together. I've tried the last one using the apply method but rather than return 0 I'd like to return the average of the previous and next values. I'm now trying to use the interpolate function so if I get it to work I'll post the answer combined with yours. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, I made some errors which I just fixed.

Comment: Yes, `Series.interpolate` is probably a good solution for filling the missing data (as well as `fillna` for basic fill operations).